# Spark cluster not respecting settings sent by submit

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I've recently begun testing Spark application performance by making minor changes in submits. However, I noticed that something isn't going as expected.

I'm facing issues at two points, which I will list here:

1. Whenever I make a submit and an application stays as ACCEPTED, the cluster automatically allocates 2GB regardless of the resource amount I set in spark-submit
2. The amount of resource used by the application is different from the amount set by spark-submit

My test spark-submit:

```
spark-submit \
  --master yarn \
  --name monit-levels \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --num-executors 6 \
  --executor-cores 2 \
  --executor-memory 2g \
  --supervise \
  --files /home/sparker/shared/application.conf \
  --class Main \
  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=4 \
  --conf spark.task.maxFailures=4 \
  --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=8 \
  shared/test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The application in ACCEPTED state:
[image]

The application in RUNNING state:
[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: In your spark-submit command you clearly said that `--executor-memory 2g`. Also, the executor memory in the spark-submit command is only the limit, and for each worker node